# How to use Regular Expression to extract command-line parameters

Tags: .net, regex, parameters, text-extraction

I have a string contain application parameters like this

```
"/u usrname /p 'password ex' /e 'Module Name.exe' /a '/w='w1w2 w3' /t='t1 t2 t3' /c=%1a /b=''' "
```

I mean using ' and ' to bound a string with spaces.

I expected to extract above string to parameters as below

```
/u
usrname
/p
password ex
/e
Module Name.exe
/a
/w='w1w2 w3' /t='t1 t2 t3' /c=%1a /b=''
```

How can I do that using regular expression?

Comment: Something like: [`(/[a-z])(?:\s*|=)(?:'?([^']*?)'?)\s*(?=/|$)`](http://regex101.com/r/aZ2jR1) (not a full answer since I don't know about .net compatibility)

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Regex.Split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string pattern = "(/\\w\\s)";
```

Comment: Great!!
It is very useful for parameter in format `/x value1 /y 'value 2'`
I will use `string pattern = "(/\\w+\\s+)";` for my parameters format with more characters in parameter's name & more space between parameter name and value like `/xyz   value1 /ab  'value 2'`

Comment: Yes, combined with regex it's extremely useful. And you're correct, using \\s+ will allow for more spaces if necessary :)